# Grid view is not displaying in the browser

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I created a web page with few labels, text boxes and grid view. When i see the page in browser, gridview is missing. what could be the reason?

I want to show some sample data in gridview. (data is not from database or xml). I would like to add one or two rows of data in gridview using html. This is to show just a prototype of web page  .

Just show all the fields in a grid . original design i'll do later.  Is it possible ? if so, how?

Thank U.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You would need to bind gridview to some data. It won't render any html anything without data.

Comment: Actually i make one grid view this one showing in web page but when i make grid view in another page this is not showing and in the first one grid view i did'nt give the bind data but it's showing

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening because you have not bind the data to the Grid View from server side.
Thats why it is not visible to the front end.